# AngularJS ng-show not firing when used with map

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Trying to use a key/value map to determine if an angular controlled element should be displayed :

http://jsfiddle.net/9fR23/181/

But I receive a exception :

```
angular.js:6173 TypeError: fnPtr is not a function
    at Object.elementFns [as get] (angular.js:6802)
    at Object.$get.Scope.$digest (angular.js:8563)
    at Object.$get.Scope.$apply (angular.js:8771)
    at angular.js:986
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:2873)
```

Using scope in this way is not illegal ? How to use a key/value map to determine if element should be displayed ? This map will be updated at runtime, so to ensure this update is reflected on UI I need to include `apply()` method ?

fiddle code :

```
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr ng-repeat="person in people">
            <td ng-show="errorMap('1')">{{ person.first + ' ' + person.last }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
myapp.controller('FirstCtrl', function ($scope) {
     var errorMap = new Object()

     errorMap['1'] = 'true'
     errorMap['2'] = 'false';
$scope.errorMap = errorMap

    $scope.people = [
        { id: 1, first: 'John', last: 'Rambo' },
        { id: 2, first: 'Rocky', last: 'Balboa' },
        { id: 3, first: 'John', last: 'Kimble' },
        { id: 4, first: 'Ben', last: 'Richards' }
    ];
});
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this error map? what r u trying to do?

Comment: if you want to map data do it on the controller.

Comment: @AdamGoldman just trying to call the function. thanks. This is now answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to call a method on your scope that is called `errorMap`.
Use square brackets to access it.

```
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr ng-repeat="person in people">
            <td ng-show="errorMap['1']">{{ person.first + ' ' + person.last }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`errorMap('1')` is not a function, its an object. so you can do this:

```
ng-show="errorMap['1']"
```